# How to write to json file using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, backend

I am building Face recognition webapp using react as frontend and node as backend. [Reference of project](https://towardsdatascience.com/facial-recognition-spa-for-bnk48-idol-group-using-react-and-face-api-js-ad62b43ec5b6).
Till now i have build frontend where we have to manually add 128-d and the name of the user as show in json file.
Json File:

```
{
"MarkZuckerberg": {
"name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
"descriptors": [
  [-0.11509660631418228,0.047304537147283554,0.06996937096118927,-0.02108921855688095,-0.17324070632457733,0.008591795340180397,-0.046306341886520386,-0.030270379036664963,0.06465639173984528,-0.1950627714395523,0.2044021636247635,-0.014686697162687778,-0.13115081191062927,0.00824546068906784,0.1082344651222229,0.11441763490438461,-0.10734807699918747,-0.11719620227813721,-0.1931850016117096,-0.057171568274497986,-0.010299241170287132,0.10951750725507736,-0.07525860518217087,0.015466967597603798,-0.21026837825775146,-0.3006324768066406,-0.004381739534437656,-0.012215236201882362,0.07295174896717072,0.007079784758388996,-0.06104493886232376,0.010193053632974625,-0.1446971595287323,-0.020350344479084015,0.051162924617528915,0.17100049555301666,-0.08372041583061218,-0.048475395888090134,0.14093193411827087,-0.02201324701309204,-0.23381589353084564,0.07185199856758118,0.03903580829501152,0.2792551517486572,0.20124436914920807,-0.0012795543298125267,0.09784051030874252,-0.03154441714286804,0.1095748171210289,-0.273921936750412,0.054020848125219345,0.0714995414018631,0.12899042665958405,0.0810670405626297,0.0241119172424078,-0.1707993447780609,0.006264302879571915,0.19223465025424957,-0.1769658327102661,0.09839855134487152,0.106398805975914,-0.10211984813213348,0.00980980321764946,-0.054217979311943054,0.25736504793167114,0.09443183988332748,-0.13063456118106842,-0.19590522348880768,0.1417907178401947,-0.21820229291915894,-0.07024678587913513,0.07265765219926834,-0.08911873400211334,-0.1514299064874649,-0.32338377833366394,0.042097702622413635,0.37956830859184265,0.14495329558849335,-0.16217286884784698,-0.01090754009783268,-0.02520592324435711,0.004018944688141346,0.07138974219560623,0.08850570023059845,-0.04169246926903725,-0.0560939684510231,-0.08213154226541519,0.04895034432411194,0.3277265727519989,0.0042845262214541435,0.022831842303276062,0.22679556906223297,0.11657196283340454,-0.09422964602708817,0.025410793721675873,0.019224854186177254,-0.10367995500564575,-0.053014203906059265,-0.03388235718011856,0.05198237672448158,-0.017041603103280067,-0.17061248421669006,0.05279357358813286,0.1559089869260788,-0.23155805468559265,0.3043012320995331,-0.10471668094396591,0.05039597675204277,0.054945606738328934,0.03542228415608406,-0.07390270382165909,-0.054555315524339676,0.1733158528804779,-0.21698439121246338,0.09403765946626663,0.20701336860656738,0.12038660049438477,0.16224659979343414,0.07085459679365158,0.07652249932289124,-0.003756454912945628,0.10730867087841034,-0.2430482804775238,-0.06863908469676971,-0.03544541820883751,-0.1186264380812645,0.06200796365737915,0.13533177971839905]
]
}
```

Next I will automate user entry part by giving option for writing user name and upload button which will directly write username and their 128-d into json file. But I'm not sure how to write into json file using the particular syntax i.e parantheses and after that name label and then descriptor label etc using node

Could someone help me how to can i add new entries into json file using node as backend?

Comment: Use the “fs” module?

Comment: And can we write in format as show in above json file image?

Comment: Why is the json file an image? Also why do you think you can’t? Wouldn’t it be good to try first?

Comment: there was no option to upload a file that's why image. Yeah you write I will give it a try. Thanks for help!

Comment: I think it’s expected that the example code is copy/pasted into the question.

Comment: yess sorry for inconvience as I am new to stackoverflow,will definitely take care in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can either import json file if it is on your filesystem, or parse it using `JSON.parse` if you have it as a string. Then edit the object as usual. After that you can stringify it back using `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Also can i append the same way as in the file? With proper parentheses before name label and two square brackets in descriptor label?

Comment: Yes, you can write or append the result in a file using `fs.writeFile` and `fs.appendFile`.

Comment: Glad to help :)